# Change position of citation using biblatex

Tags: biblatex

Some journals require inline citations in parentheses/brackets, while others require superscript citations. At the end of a sentence, inline citations are usually typeset before the period, while superscript citations are typeset after the period. The *cite* package used with bibtex automatically takes care of moving the citation in the right position.

Here is a MWE with inline citation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{cite}

\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
@article{fragoso2016,
  title = {Epidemiology of {{Chronic Obstructive Pulmonary Disease}} ({{COPD}}) in {{Aging Populations}}},
  volume = {13},
  issn = {1541-2563},
  doi = {10.3109/15412555.2015.1077506},
  language = {eng},
  timestamp = {2017-02-09T11:28:32Z},
  number = {2},
  journal = {COPD},
  author = {Fragoso, Carlos A. Vaz},
  year = {2016},
  keywords = {Aging,COPD,Epidemiology,GOLD,Spirometry},
  pages = {125--129}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
A statement \cite{fragoso2016}.

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{biblio}
\end{document}
```

Adding the "super" option to *cite*, I get "A statement.<sup>1</sup>" instead of "A statement [1].".

Using biblatex, it is easy to move from inline to superscript citations (just change globally \cite into \supercite), but I could not find a way to automatically move the superscript citation after the period. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You could use the `\autocite` command, that takes care of moving punctuation if the right options are enabled.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Works fine for me:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[autocite=superscript]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
A statement \autocite{doody}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

And with `\usepackage[autocite=plain]{biblatex}`:

[image]

Comment: It works fine indeed! It seems like I had only a vague idea of how \autocite works! Thanks!